# It's $M$ the centroid of $\triangle ABC$?

Tags: geometry, inequality

Let $ABC$ a triangle and $M$ a point inside it. Find the minimum of $MA^2+MB^2+MC^2$.

It's $M$ the centroid of $\triangle ABC$?

Comment: Your question is not clear - how is the value $MA^2$ is defined when M is a point?

Comment: @Moti $MA$ is a length of a segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a triangle on an $xy$-plane, where $A=(x_1, y_1)$, $B=(x_2, y_2)$, $C=(x_3, y_3)$.

Let $P = (s,t)$. The sum of squared distances from $P$ to vertices is

$$\begin{align*}
d(s,t) &= PA^2 + PB^2 + PC^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^3\left[(s-x_i)^2+(t-y_i)^2\right]\\
&= 3s^2+3t^2-2s\sum_{i=1}^3x_i-2t\sum_{i=1}^3y_i + \sum_{i=1}^3(x_i^2+y_i^2)
\end{align*}$$

As a quadratic function in $s$ with fixed $t, x_i,y_i$, the minimum of $d(s,t)$ happens independent of $t$ when

$$s = -\frac{-2\sum_{i=1}^3x_i}{2\cdot 3} = \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}$$

Similarly, as a quadratic function in $t$ with fixed $s, x_i, y_i$, the minimum of $d(s,t)$ happens independent of $s$ when

$$t = -\frac{-2\sum_{i=1}^3y_i}{2\cdot 3} = \frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3}$$

These $s,t$ are the same as the coordinates of the centroid $G$ of $\triangle ABC$, given by formula

$$G = \left(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}, \frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3}\right)$$